# Silverlight: How to Bind to UIElement in another TabItem?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, tabitem, uielement

I have a Silverlight `TabControl` which has two `TabItem`s. In the second, I have a `TextBox`, and I want to bind its `Text` property to an other `TextBox`'s `Text` property, *which is in the first `TabItem`*.

`ElementName` doesn't work, the `Path` for `RelativeSource` is way too long. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a view model, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, make both textbox datacontext to this view model, and bind to the relevant property, if you don't understand I'll provide code.